# Как сортировать массив структур по одному из параметров структуры?

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, visual-c++, структуры

```
struct Student
{
    char last_name[m];
    char name[m];
    char surname[m];
    int proga[n];
    int sda[n];
    int mat_analiz[n];
    int lin_algebra[n];
    int sum_ball;
}student[k];
```

Подскажите как отсортировать данную структуру по переменой `sum_ball`, и если совпадает то по `last_name` 
Как ни пробовал, ничего не получается, просто выдает какую-то ахинею.
Раньше с таким не приходилось работать.

```
Student temp;   

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (student[j].sum_ball < student[i].sum_ball)
        {
            temp.last_name = student[i].last_name;
            student[i].last_name = student[j].last_name;
            student[j].last_name = temp;
            //и так дали с другими 

        }
    }
}
```

Ну например вот так, с массивами так можно а с структурами как? Это ж не правильно я понимаю

Comment: Приведите код, а мы его подправим. Нужно просто правильно написать компаратор и правильно передать его алгоритму сортировки...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Требуемый компаратор может выглядеть, например, так:

```
[](const Student&a, const Student&b)
{
    if (a.sum_ball < b.sum_ball) return true;
    if (a.sum_ball == b.sum_ball) 
        return strcmp(a.last_name,b.last_name) < 0;
    return false;
}
```

Вроде бы так...