# Сортировка структур в си

Tags: c, сортировка, структуры

Подскажите как удобнее всего отсортировать данную структуру по уменьшению значения data[i].price

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct size // габаритные размеры
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct NOTEBOOK
{
    char model[21]; // наименование
    struct size ss;
    float w; // вес
    int price; // цена
    int MHz;
    int max_ozu;
    float diagonal;
    int video_memory;
    char display[10];
    int regen;
    float HDD_memory;
};

#define FORMAT "%20s%4d%3f%4fx%4fx%4f%3d%2d%4f%1d%9s%2d%5f"
#define VARLIST data[i].model, &data[i].price, &data[i].w,&data[i].ss.x, &data[i].ss.y,&data[i].ss.z,&data[i].MHz,&data[i].max_ozu,&data[i].diagonal,&data[i].video_memory,data[i].display,&data[i].regen,&data[i].HDD_memory

int main()
{
    struct NOTEBOOK data[20];
    FILE *from, *toto;
    from = fopen("note.txt", "r");
    toto = fopen("toto.bin", "wb");
    int i=0,count=0;

    while (fscanf(from, FORMAT, VARLIST) != EOF) {
    // Здесь идёт запись в toto;
    // Печать введённой строки
    if (data[i].MHz>120)
        {
            count++;
            fwrite(&data,sizeof(struct NOTEBOOK),20,toto);


    printf("%2d) %15s %d %.1f  %.1fx%.1fx%.1f %3d %d %.1f %d %s %d %.3f \n", i+1,
        data[i].model, data[i].price, data[i].w,data[i].ss.x, data[i].ss.y,
         data[i].ss.z,data[i].MHz,data[i].max_ozu,data[i].diagonal,data[i].video_memory,
         data[i].display,data[i].regen,data[i].HDD_memory
         );
         i++;
        }

    }
    printf("\n%d",count);
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сортировать массив структур по одному из параметров структуры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748728/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Маленький пример

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct notebook_t
{
    char model[20];
    int  price;
} notebook_t;


int cmpf(const void *_a, const void *_b)
{
    notebook_t *a = (notebook_t *) _a;
    notebook_t *b = (notebook_t *) _b;
    return b->price - a->price;
}

int main()
{
    notebook_t n[] =
    {
        {"Acer",    33},
        {"Asus",    54},
        {"Lenovo",  29},
        {"Samsung", 30}
    };
    size_t qty = sizeof(n) / sizeof(n[0]);
    qsort(n, qty, sizeof(notebook_t), cmpf);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < qty; i++)
        printf("%s %d\n", n[i].model, n[i].price);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А для поиска использовать `bsearch`

Comment: Опять эта грубая порочная практика "сравнивать" целые значения путем вычитания... И в приведении типов зачем-то потерян `const`. Причем явный каст как раз и притянут за уши, чтобы "убить" `const`. Зачем? Для вычисления размера массива элегантно использован `sizeof(n[0])` (пусть и с лишними скобками), а далее в вызове `qsort` вдруг ни с того ни с с его `sizeof(notebook_t)`. Что за каша? Несколько человек код писало?

Comment: @AnT **Опять эта грубая порочная практика** - Если не секрет, а как выглядит нежная беспорочная практика сравнения целых ?

Comment: @Serge: Спасибо за ваш хороший вопрос, Сергей! Нежная непорочная православно-винрарная идиома для генерации "трехзначного" сравнения двух значений `a` и `b` выглядит так: `(a > b) - (a < b)`. Таким незамысловатым способом вы можете сравнить практически любые фундаментальные типы (включая плавающие и указатели) без риска переполнения.

Comment: **(a > b) - (a < b)** - Скажите, а вы никогда не слыхали, что на уровне процессора команда СРАВНЕНИЯ выполняется посредством выполнения ВЫЧИТАНИЯ ? Разница между этими двумя этими группами команд заключается в том, что вычитание ЗАГРУЖАЕТ результат, а сравнение - нет. А вот биты признаков результата и биты переполнения обе эти группы команд выставляют абсолютно одинаково. Ну посмотрите (к примеру) главу 4.3.5. в документе "Book E: Enhanced PowerPC Architecture". То же относится и к другим архитектурам.